# Why is chrome highlighting a margin that is not listed in styles or computed

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

There are no margin styles being shown under "styles", and as you can see it doesn't show any being computed either. No idea what's going on here but I noticed this right after changing the width of the element to 90%. I'm using foundation so maybe its some competing styles?

**I'm not asking how to fix my specific issue which is why I've posted no code. I'm just confused why chrome would highlight a margin when its not showing any to be computed**

Comment: You should post more code. Your image isn't enough to identify the problem.

Comment: I'm not really asking how to fix my issue, I'm just confused why chrome would ever show the highlight when its not showing any computed margin. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Because it may not be margin. Is there any relative positioning going on?

Comment: And my asking for code isn't necessarily to fix your problem. It would be helpful in, like I said, identifying the source.

Comment: I haven't added any myself but there could be some being added by foundation. But yea it would just be a huge deal to clean up the code so that it could be posted as its kind of a mess right now. But can you elaborate on how it might not be a margin? It sounds like that might answer my question. It was my assumption that a highlight of that color always meant margin.

Comment: And its too late to post it now because I fixed it with display:inline-block, but I would still like to figure out why chrome shows that highlight

Comment: I can only go by the data on the image you posted. Can't elaborate more with certainty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is caused by the `display: block` rule.

The element is occupying the entire horizontal space of its parent, so Chrome tries to convey that by coloring the occupied space with the margin color.

Change the rule to either `display: inline-block` or `display: inline` to remedy the issue.

Comment: My problem was that this was causing one of my elements to be offset to the left a bit so I slapped a `margin: 0 auto` on it and BAM! centered that bad boy up!

Answer (score 1):

My guess here would be that the containing `small-4` possibly has a padding? Or Chrome is trying to be smart.

Answer (score 0):

Totally get what you are talking about. What you are asking for is: Where can I see the rules for example “body { margin: 10px; }” that is somehow the default in Chrome. I only know this because when I set the margin to 0, I can see a substantial jump in my text’s indentation. Also as you mentioned in the Chrome there is a highlight that should not theoretically be there. Hence some default “padding” or “margin” being added. Not sure what level you on but you might want to look at the reset of these values to answer your question: https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/