# Bootstrap adding hidden Margins to Columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, margin, bootstrap-4

For some reason bootstrap is adding a hidden margin to my column classes. When I inspect on an element which is currently 'col-lg-3' it does not show any margin CSS and even if I add margin:0 to the column it still adds a margin.

Please see image below.

I have been looking around for a while, and I am quite shocked I have not been able to find an answer to this. Does anyone have any insight in whats going wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC0qd.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41864881/1528308

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is chrome highlighting a margin that is not listed in styles or computed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511434/why-is-chrome-highlighting-a-margin-that-is-not-listed-in-styles-or-computed)

Comment: Where is the code? Post it in the question.

Comment: You may want to remove the padding, you can use the `p-0` class for that.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because your element tries to occupy all the width that the father has, you can modify that by adding display: inline-flex or display: flex;

Comment: I fully understand, but why should I have to add to the bootstrap CSS to change this. This problem has not come up anywhere else within the site?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if what you're saying is margin or padding.
Margin is the space before and after the columns
Padding is the space inside the column.

If want your content to start at the very edge of the column, then you do:

```
.col-*-* { padding: 0 }
```

Comment: Yes it is the margin. It is adding a margin to the element.